# ¿Como puedo obtener los productos con sus precios actuales? (SQL)

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, sql

Me encuentro trabado tratando de seleccionar los productos con sus precios actuales...

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

producto <pid PK, descripcion, tipo, contenido>

tipo <tipo PK, descripcion>

comercio <comercio PK, nombre, direccion, barrio, zona>

precio <pid PK FK, comercio PK FK, fecha_registro PK, precio>

```
Lo resolví con este código:
```

```sql
SELECT pre.pid, pre.precio

FROM precio pre

WHERE pre.fecha_registro=(SELECT MAX(fecha_registro)
                          FROM precio
                          WHERE pre.pid=precio.pid)

GROUP BY pre.pid, pre.precio
;
```

PD: Con esa subconsulta me quedo con los precios de las fechas más actuales hasta el día de hoy.

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo la relación entre las tablas (comercio, precio, producto) solo nos falta encontrar el método para que nos devuelva el precio más actualizado para cada producto y comercio.

Para obtener el precio más actual recurrimos a un `MAX` y a una subconsulta que devuelve justamente lo que buscábamos: un registro por producto y comercio. A esta sub consulta unimos (mediante `JOIN`) las otras dos tablas para obtener el detalle de los comercios y de los productos.

Finalmente podemos añadir una cláusula `WHERE` para acotar el comercio y/o el producto buscado.

```
SELECT nombre, direccion, barrio, zona, producto.descripcion, precio
FROM comercio
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT pid, comercio, max(fecha_registro), precio
   FROM precio
   GROUP BY pid, comercio, precio
) b on comercio.comercio = b.comercio
INNER JOIN producto on producto.pid = b. pid
WHERE producto.descripcion = 'Coca cola'
```

Comment: Gracias! Ya edite la consulta y puse la solución!